# (14.04) Problem interacting with applications after opening gnome dashboard

Tags: gnome, cursor

Recently I had to reinstall ubuntu 14.04/gnome and I noticed a really annoying problem. When I move my cursor to the top left to open my dashboard, I can click on a window but after it comes to the front I cant interact with it. Should I just remove and install gnome again?

Comment: When you click, it makes it come to the front - that is designed. You shouldn't be able to interact, just click once and it comes to the front.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that after it comes to the front I cant interact with it

Comment: Oh. Hmm that is strange. Is this all applications? Reinstalling is not the answer at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, even system applications like Files

Comment: A reinstall is unlikely to solve anything as this was a fresh install. Try enabling a proprietary driver. (open Software centre, Edit, software sources, 5th tab (aditional drivers), enable the latest one).

Comment: Cool, glad to help!